# How to throttle an infinite observable to maintain a constant number of items in process?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have an infinite observable generated from periodic sampling of an enumerable:

```
    private static IObservable<Runjob> GetRunjobObservable(IEnumerable<Runjob> runjobs)
    {
        var observable = Observable.Create<Runjob>(obs =>
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = _interval;
            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => obs.OnNext(runjobs.Sample(1, true).Single());
            return timer;
        });
        return observable;
    }
```

I would like to subject this stream of runjobs to processing on different threads, but with the condition that no more than 10 runjobs are processed at any given time.  It is not important that every runjob in the observable be processed - my intent is to get a bunch of processes running simultaneously and on an ongoing basis for stress test purposes.

I have the following code.  How do I modify it so that a maximum of 10 runjobs are processed at any given time?

```
 var runjobObs = GetRunjobObservable(runjobs);
 var replies = runjobObs
            .SubscribeOn(new EventLoopScheduler(t => new Thread(t) {Name = _threadCounter++.ToString(), IsBackground = true}))
            .ObserveOn(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
            .Select(HandleRunjob);
```

My Rx is a little rusty, so if you see anything wrong with my example, please do correct me.

Comment: This is a bad idea having a `System.Timers.Timer` inside of an `Observable.Create`.  Why not do `var observable = Observable.Interval(_interval).Select(_ => runjobs.Sample(1, true).Single());`?

Comment: You probably want something like this: `Observable.Interval(_interval).Select(_ => runjobs.Sample(1, true).Single()).Select(x => Observable.Start(() => HandleRunJob(x))).Merge(10);`